# How can remove index.php from url

Tags: codeigniter, url

when I mouse over or click on anchor links then it shows

```
http://localhost/code-testing/index.php/about-us.
```

I tried base_url() and site_url() too but the result is same.how can I remove that 'index.php' from the url ?

-Thanks.

***Resolved:***

Thank you everybody for your kind answers. I'm using xampp and this one worked for me

code-testing/application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url']= 'http://localhost/code-testing/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

code-testing/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

and the following links then worked without showing 'index.php' in the url

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('home');?>">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('about_us');?>">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('contact');?>">Contact Us</a></li>
```

Comment: but sorry that post didn't show the full way to do that. as there didn't say what should write for $config['uri_protocol'] = '?'; in config.php, so I didn't get that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 steps to remove index.php

1.Make below changes in application/config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Your Ci folder_name';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

2.Make .htacces file in your root directory using below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

3.Enable rewrite mode

i. First, initiate it with the following command:

**a2enmod rewrite**

ii. Edit the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

change the **AllowOverride None** to **AllowOverride All**.

iii. Restart your server with the following command:

**sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart**

Comment: @user1844626:welcome dude

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable empty as below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

try to replace following variable with these parameters `('AUTO', 'PATH_INFO', 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_URI', and 'ORIG_PATH_INFO')` one by one

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the.htaccess file in the application root directory, along with the index.php file. (Check if the htaccess extension is correct , Bz htaccess.txt did not work for me.)

And Add the following rules to .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then find the following line in your application/config/config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Set the variable empty as below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

That's it, it worked for me.

If it doesn't work further try to replace following variable with these parameters ('AUTO', 'PATH_INFO', 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_URI', and 'ORIG_PATH_INFO') one by one

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```