# Codeigniter links broken in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink, broken-links

I am working on updating a project for a company. I transferred files to my localhost. So project is in "localhost/project/". When I open the website in the browser all the links point to "localhost/filename", directory up a level from project folder. I did some research around, and noticed poeple suggesting changing the htaccess, but still couldn't get the right result. And suggestiong please let me know. If you want anything on my part just ask. Thank!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Start :

```
http://localhost/projectfolder/

<a href="/" title="">Home</a>
```

leads to :

```
http://localhost/
```

Config.php :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectfolder/';
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
$config['url_suffix'] = ".html";
$config['language'] = "english";
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z & + 0-9~%.:_\-,\'?';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['cache_path'] = '';
$config['encryption_key'] = "";
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

Comment: What is your .htaccess atm?

Comment: Could you please add it in your question using the right formatting?

Comment: This may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017448/how-can-remove-index-php-from-url/15017916#15017916

Comment: this may be help you: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017448/how-can-remove-index-php-from-url/15017916#15017916

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to open your config.php file and change the base_url value to localhost or possibly localhost:8080 (or whatever port your localhost uses).

**EDIT**

The problem is that all of your anchor tags are using hard coded values such as `/` for the homepage.

On a server this will work fine because your domain is something like `example.com` so by going to `/`, you're saying go to `example.com/`.

The correct way to create links in codeigniter is to use either the `anchor()` helper, or manually create an anchor tag as your project has, but use either `base_url()` or `site_url()` in the href.

An example of how you can fix the links to your homepage, is like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/">blah</a>
```

It may work for all your links to just prefix your href value with the base_url, but it depends on the value in the links.

Here's a link to the codeigniter helper methods - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html.

It would be in your best interest to take a look at the codeigniter manual as it's very good.

Comment: Where is that file located?

Comment: /application/config/config.php

Comment: Ok so what url brings your app up in a browser, and what url do you get when you click a link that does not work?

Comment: Also, are you using mamp, or wamp, or somethign else?

Comment: localhost/projectname brings up home page || Using WAMP || when I click on "home link" it takes me to localhost;wamp home page

Comment: You're saying by clicking a link takes you to "localhost;wamp"?

Comment: no takes me up a level from project folder. website it located at localhost/project, a "home page" link leads to localhost

Comment: Ok please post the exact url (including http://) that you start at, and then please post the exact url that you get after clicking a link. Also post the contents of your config.php file. To post these things, please edit your question and add them.

Comment: Can you also post the link to your homepage?

Comment: We need to see what the code is that they are using to link to the home page. If it's a simple `<a href="somepage"></a>`, it's not going to work locally without changing all the links. If they're using the codeigniter helper methods, it should be able to work locally by tweaking a few configs. I need to see all the pieces to the puzzle though

Comment: It's just a simple link. I put into the question

Comment: If you think my answer is acceptable, please click the checkbox in order to give me credit, and also to help you build some reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

to

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple .htaccess it seems to work for me: Yours is missing the ReWriteBase

---

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /projectfolder/

    # If the start of the URL doesn't match one of these...
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|uploads|css|images|js)

    # Route through index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

---

If that works for you, I suppose you could start by fixing the ReWriteBase in yours.

Please note that when you upload this htaccess file to your host and the default base_url changes to something like www.example.com, you have to change the ReWriteBase to /

and don't forget to use `<?php echo base_url() ?>` in your links where possible.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

use this in config file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Your project folder  name';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

use this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and enable rewrite mode using below command

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and also Edit the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
change all the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.
```