# codeigniter's redirect redirects me to index.php constantly

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I'm using a dull redirection :

```
redirect('/home/login/');
```

for when the user is not logged. But it keeps redirecting me to

```
/index.php/home/login/
```

While I have this in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: this may help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017448/how-can-remove-index-php-from-url/15017916#15017916

Comment: thanks. It helped! It always worked without removing the index.php from the config files because I wasn't using redirect in my earlier projects. You should post this as the answer so I can vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible solution 1:**

*make .htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /#MY_DIRECTORY#

    RewriteRule ^(#MY_DEFAULT_CONTROLLER#(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

*EDIT My_Application_Folder\Config.php*

```
$config['base_url'] = '/#MY_DIRECTORY#';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

**Possible solution 2:**

*make .htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /#MY_DIRECTORY#
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

*EDIT My_Application_Folder\Config.php*

```
$config['base_url'] = '/#MY_DIRECTORY#';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Note: #MY_DIRECTORY# is on live server subdom directory (eg. first.example.com) - just for example and handling multiple application on one system CI

Don't forget to set for files rules in htaccess or in output custom library

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
```

**1 YEAR**

```
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</filesMatch>
```

**2 HOURS**

```
<filesMatch ".(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

**CACHED FOREVER /MOD_REWRITE TO RENAME EVERY CHANGE**

```
<filesMatch ".(js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</filesMatch>
```