# Codeigniter - hide index.php with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

My website:

> http://ibnight.com

When trying to access an event in my website by:

> http://ibnight.com/1

I get a not found error:

> The requested URL /1 was not found on this server.

Works only if I access it with the index.php in url, like:

> http://ibnight.com/index.php/1

My controller is something like:

```
class Events extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {}

    public function index()
    {}

    public function event()
    {}

}
```

My routing:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'events';
$route['(:num)'] = $route['default_controller'] . '/event/$1';
```

My config:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017448/how-can-remove-index-php-from-url/15017916#15017916

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```